# calculate fiscal year issue

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the fiscal year from this following code. But I am getting year 13 instead of 12. What could be wrong? Please suggest.

```
calculateFiscalYearForDate(date("m/d/y"), "10/1", "9/30");

function calculateFiscalYearForDate($inputDate, $fyStart, $fyEnd)
    {
        $date = strtotime($inputDate);
        $inputyear = strftime('%y',$date);

        $fystartdate = strtotime($fyStart.$inputyear);
        $fyenddate = strtotime($fyEnd.$inputyear);

        if($date < $fyenddate){
            $fy = intval($inputyear);
        }else{
            $fy = intval(intval($inputyear) + 1);
        }
        return $fy;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong where? What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a forward-slash:

```
    $fystartdate = strtotime($fyStart."/".$inputyear);
    $fyenddate = strtotime($fyEnd."/".$inputyear);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/v6er4ePt

Comment: Also by the way. no matter what date you put in there, the result will always be 12... not sure what the parameters are for....